# Merge records in LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am very new into LINQ

I have following 2 queries:

```
var ticketStatus = from lookup in lookupDetails.AsEnumerable()
                   join ticket in ticketDetails
                       on lookup.LookupDetailID equals ticket.Status
                   select ticket;

var ticketSev = from lookupSev in lookupDetails.AsEnumerable()
                join ticket in ticketDetails
                    on lookupSev.LookupDetailID equals ticket.Status
                select ticket;

var finalTicket = ...
```

Now I want to merge `ticketStatus` and `ticketSev` into `finalTicket`. How can I achieve this task? I dont want to use Join.

Comment: Aren't those two queries exactly the same or am I missing something?

Comment: @dtb: The first query joins `lookup` against `ticket`, while the second one joins `lookupSev` against `ticket`.

Answer (score 3):

Simple use this to Concatenate and remove duplicate

```
var finalTicket = ticketStatus.Union(ticketSev);
```

To Simple concatenation and sort. Duplicates are preserved. use **.Concat()** on place of **.Union()**

To implement this in best way follow the following links:
[How to: Combine and Compare String Collections (LINQ)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546148.aspx)
[Merging two Collection<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56078/merging-2-collectiont)
[Create a list from two object lists with linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/720609/merge-two-object-lists-with-linq)

Answer (score 2):

```
var finalTicket = ticketStatus.Union(ticketSev);   // remove duplicates
var finalTicket = ticketStatus.Concat(ticketSev);  // keep duplicates
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say *how* you want to merge them, so I'll assume you want the union of both sets (i.e. combining them and eliminating duplicates):

```
var finalTicket = ticketStatus.Union(ticketSev);
```

If you want to keep duplicates or know there won't be any, you can concatenate the sequences instead:

```
var finalTicket = ticketStatus.Concat(ticketSev);
```